# nothing return using select statement

Tags: 7, database

I'm using this code in a views PHP field and I can't figure out how to select a column using a date condition

```
$year = $_GET['field_mstudent_date_value']['value']['year']; //get the year from date filter  

$month = $_GET['field_mstudent_date_value']['value']['month']; //get the month from date filter

if (strlen($month) == 1) {
    $month = '0' . $month;
}

$resault = db_query("SELECT entity_id FROM {field_data_field_exp_date} WHERE   
  YEAR(field_exp_date_value) = $year   
AND MONTH(field_exp_date_value) = $month   
AND revision_id = $entity_id;"); //field_exp_date_value is date field yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format

foreach ($resault as $value) {
    echo $value->entity_id;
}
```

Why do I get no results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) the `MONTH` function does not return zero-padded values for single-digit months. Your code tries to use zero-padding, however. In case you really would like to use zero-padding, you should use quotes around your condition value.

Additionally, you don't specify in your code sample where you get the `$entity_id`, so what kiamlaluno said in his answer (now deleted) about the entity ID being different from the revision ID might well be valid as well.

A good starting point is to use a more generic tool for database access, for example `drush sqlc`, to debug your query.

As for putting variable values into the query without using placeholders, I have to agree with kiamlaluno: You open up for SQL injections.